# Separate css class

Tags: 7

Only for front page I want separate css body class. If a apply in html.tpl.php then it is applicable on each page. How can I apply condition for front page?

Answer (score 0):

In your template.php check the `drupal_is_front_page` function, if it is true use the [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) to load extra css styles.

Comment: In template.php,`if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme').'/css/home.css'); 
}`, whats wrong in this?

Comment: you need to put this code in `THEME_preprocess_page`